# Can't include / use inAppBrowser in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

**I've taken a look at the other questions but none of the solutions worked**

Here is my line of code:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

Here is the error:

`cordova is not defined` (or `InAppBrowser is not defined` if I remove cordova in the code)

Here are my **config.xml** includes:

```
(...)  
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"  />
(...)
<access origin="*"/>
 <feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
(...)
```

I **have done nothing more**. I have not installed via `cordova plugin (...)` command on **Windows 10** because `'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` in the command line interface. I have **only** installed Phonegap. I think I understand what I am missing but I do **not** understand how I should do about it in windows. Can someone help me get there? Tyvm! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it and did something like this.

```
    var ref = window.open('http://mylink.com','_blank','location=yes','closebuttoncaption=Return');
```

Here's a reference:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html